# Встроить xslt в xml или xslt и xml в html

Tags: xml, xslt

Есть необходимость в одном файле объединить и данные в формате xml и xslt шаблоны для их отображения. И чтобы браузер все это выводил в таком же виде, как если бы это были отдельные файлы.

Предположительно, если есть такая возможность - то или если xslt встроить в файл xml или если таблицу xslt и xml данные встроить в файл html.

Вопрос: реально ли это, и, если да - то как?

Comment: [Тут](http://handsontable.com/) почитайте, но без определённой подготовки данных, напрямую вставить xlst файл не получиться.

Comment: Да, это реально. Посмотрите [здесь](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32533660/5045688). Но, вообще, браузеры очень плохо поддерживают xslt. Поэтому лучше делать трансформацию на сервере, а клиенту отдавать готовый html.